# What are the limits of inverse hyperbolic sine for regression?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, econometrics, logarithm

I know that if your data contains zeros, log transforming your variable can be problematic, and all the zeros become missing. It is often suggested to use the inverse hyperbolic sine transform, rather than log shift transform (e.g. asinh(y) rather than log(y +.1)), as it is equal to approximately log(2y), so for regression purposes, it is interpreted (approximately) the same as a logged variable.

I know if your variable contains values $\in [0,1)$ , then the inverse hyperbolic sine transform is no longer a good approximation of log(2y). But are there other limitations to be aware of? for instance, if my data has a HUGE number of zeros, (say the 50th percentile is 0), like if I am looking at rental income where a majority of people have none, then are there any additional reasons to be cautious about still using the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation?

Comment: How are you using this variable in your analysis?

Comment: I am using the variable as a dependent variable in a regression analysis. I was planning on logging the dependent variable, but was also going to use inverse hyperbolic sine due to the large presence of zeros. I was just curious about 'problems' or things that should be considered when using the inverse hyperbolic sine transformation, or if the behavior of such a function is not as desirable in situations such as having a huge number of zero values

Comment: Usually there are better solutions.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=independent+zero+log+regression for some examples.

Comment: The 50th percentile being zero is consistent with a very small number of zeros, as when just about half the values are negative. More seriously, what are you worried about? The major issue is always getting the functional form about right, and a spike in any marginal distribution is just what it is.